# Getting ClassNotFoundException in test scope

Tags: maven, maven-2

I'm trying to run tests for my webapp. I've used Spring and Hibernate for it. But running `mvn package` results in an ClassNotFoundException in the test tasks: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`

I already tried adding this into my pom.xml, but without success:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

What to do here?

**UPDATE**

`mvn -X clean package`: http://paste.ubuntuusers.de/raw/409407/

Comment: Can you post the output of `mvn -X clean package`?

Comment: Try removing <scope>test</scope>.

Comment: Could you show us a `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @dtrunk The java.lang.ClassNotFoundException seems to be gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with DBCP here. Rather log says about some problems with autowiring Spring beans, starting with missing `com.example.model.ArticleService`. Declare such missing beans as Spring components and should be OK.

Comment: It seems it was a clean problem... Now it works with <scope>test</scope>